# Symbolic linked images not loading in Electron app in Windows

Tags: html, css, reactjs, electron

If I open the symbolic link with PAINT, I can see the expected image. So it means that the symbolic link is working.

The only issue is when I load the image using Electron app in Windows.

```
.fullscreenBackground{
    background-image: url("../myimage.png");
}
```

`myimage.png` points to `/../src/logo.png`.

And it works if I directly provide the path like below

```
.fullscreenBackground{
    background-image: url("../../src/logo.png");
}
```

Also no warning on the console.